# What does an empty dice mean?

Tags: witcher-adventure-game

When battling an enemy, I often get an empty dice that cannot be used.
Does this just mean I had bad luck or can this dice be used for anything?

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image: screenshot of the dice]

Comment: okay before people complain: Yes, this game is in beta, but it is available to basically everyone who signed up for the galaxy client / Beta. And everyone got 2 keys. So i think it is still valid to ask here.

Comment: Is it widely available to the public, or only those who got into the Beta/signed up for the client?

Comment: Only if you signed up for now, but isn't that the same as "buying" a game? It is still available.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is, could I go now/tomorrow/whatever and sign up, or is it a closed thing? (I know nothing about it, so I am trying to determine the extent of the beta and how closed off it is or isn't.)

Comment: @AshleyNunn I dont know how often they invite new people, but I signed up just a week ago or so and got my key with everyone else today. All my friends that signed up got 2 keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had previously spent some time to prepare spells, some development cards allow you to convert those dice into other symbols to help you win battles. Triss seems to be quite bad at regular combat, so spells are quite important for her.